# Magento Registration form no longer submitting

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been editing the built in RWD theme but have run into a problem where my registration form is no longer submitting.

It was working at one stage, but after trying to integrate the COMPANY NAME field into the registration field, i noticed it would no longer submit.

After clicking the submit button, the page reloads with the same fields filled out.

I went as far as rolling back the system to when i'm almost sure it was still working, as well as replacing the register.html from the sample content but with no change. I'm not sure what I did that caused the form to break down..

Here is my current `register.phtml` located in **public_html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form**

And a live demo: http://www.diegocordero.com.au/magento/customer/account/create/

```
<?php /**  * Create account form template  *  * @see app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
*/ /** @var $this Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register */ ?> <div class="account-create">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
            <p class="form-instructions"><?php echo $this->__('Please enter the following information to create your account.') ?></p>
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address')) ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_taxvat = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_taxvat') ?>
            <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_taxvat->setTaxvat($this->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
            <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li><?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
                <li class="hidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Company')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Telephone')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address')) ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
            <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:street<?php echo $_i ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getStreet($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Street Address %s', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="hidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                <?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
                    <li class="control">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
                        </div>
                        <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
                    </li>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
            </ul>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="back-link"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Register')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
        <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
        <?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
    </script> </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add form key after form tag

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

or

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file, make sure to clean the cache, then the original is used.

And make sure the form key is submitted.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by make sure the form key is submitted?? Thanks for the reply

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/43963/217

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code in my demo magento and its working perfectly. So try to trace your code from app/code/core/mage/customer/controllers/createpost action after submit your form.

Comment: any idea as to what may have caused this? it was working and seems to have suddenly broken down..