# Calling Login from template to cms page issue

Tags: magento-1.9, template, cms, login

I Have problem with calling login form into a page.

I build a .phtml file called `members.phtml` & `login.phtml` locate on `base/default/template/members`

**members.phtml**

```
    <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <?php $loadHtml = 'Hi Logged User...welcome'; ?>
      <div>
        <?php echo $loadHtml; ?>
      </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php $loadHtml = 'Please register or login if already registered.'; ?>

      <div>
        <?php echo $loadHtml; ?>
      </div>
        <?php echo this->getLayout()->createBlock('members/login')->setTemplate('members/login.phtml')->toHtml();  // show login form ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

`login.phtml` I copied from standard `customer/account` login folder

Then I create CMS -> Page -> Members

the content of that page is

```
{{block type="core/template" name="membersState" template="members/members.phtml"}}
```

**The problem is :**

The login block doesn't show when **guest user** accessing the Member Page, does the code that I used is wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Don't worry, English is not at all a problem here as long as we understand what your real question is. :)

Your CMS page content looks good. But your `members.phtml` file has a small problem. Problem resides exactly here :

```
<?php echo this->getLayout()->createBlock('members/login')->setTemplate('members/login.phtml')->toHtml();  // show login form ?>
```

Problems are given below:

1. You are using `this`. It is wrong. It should be `$this`.
2. You are trying to create a  block of type `customer/login` which Magento is unaware of. You really need to use a block type which Magento knows. In this particular context, the block type is `customer/form_login`. So your code will look like this.

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('members/login.phtml')->toHtml();  // show login form ?>
   ```

I believe this will resolve your problem. Good luck

Comment: wow.. thank you so much @rajeev-k-tomy for the explanation, yes it's indeed resolved my problem. all above answer is also resolved my problem, but I don't wanna call mini.login.form.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code to call mini.login.phtml

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('customer/form/mini.login.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done some mistake on  code.

If you have using magento default login form then you need to change

You should change **Block type** `members/login` to `customer/form_login`.Also You need to change template file  to `customer/form/mini.login.phtml` from `members/login.phtml`.

Also as per as ,my concept  ***base/default/template/members*** folder does **not exit in default magento**.You may be use  ***3rd party extension*** or 
***have done some customization***

If Your template have feature then you may be miss form key  at that form.See details at [What is getBlockHtml('formkey')?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43962/what-is-getblockhtmlformkey)

Comment: thank-you for the answer @amit-bera but it's not what I looking for