# Not Loggin in from front-end: Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I have register and login links on my website. Register is working fine but when i tried to login it again come back to the login screen with out any error message.

I have tried to re-write the htaccess for my site but still the same issue.

Any help Will Be appreciated:

Here is the link:

https://www.dauerusa.com/customer/account/login/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Customized template? I guess you are missing `form_key` field. Add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` just below your `<form>` opening tag.

You can read more about `form_key` here: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/43963/208

EDIT:

Template file is located in `app\design\frontend\[PACKAGE]\[THEME]\template\persistent\customer\form\login.phtml` or `app\design\frontend\[PACKAGE]\[THEME]\template\customer\form\login.phtml` depending on your configuration.

Comment: I am using default magento tempalte not the customized

Comment: Its auto logged me in when i register a new account but not working when i direct login through login form Here 
https://www.dauerusa.com/customer/account/login/

Comment: Then it's probably issue in the Shopper theme you are using. If you inspect the page source you will see that form_key field is missing.

Comment: where i can edit my form to add that code? @Lord Skeletor

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: I have this directory "app/design/frontend/default/shopper/template/customer/form" but there is no any login.phtml there

Comment: here is the screenshot for configuration: http://screencast.com/t/Wy1VxWVA