# Customer tab incorrect data

Tags: magento-1.9

I have incorrect customer added in back-end . its virus or something else anyone facing this kind of the issue .

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: you have formkey in customer registration and formkey  check at registration data save in same controller createPostAction

Comment: I don't have idea about it . can you please explain it in detail

Comment: Can you add captcha to your form?

Comment: i don't have any captcha in new customer registration form ?

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43962/what-is-getblockhtmlformkey